# How can I get a new instance of a DbContext injected per class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Configure Ef Core db context to be injected as separate instance for each class rather than per call, is it feasible? I could not find any overload to achieve that.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")).EnableSensitiveDataLogging());
}
```

Comment: You want it as a [transient service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.1#service-lifetimes) rather than a scoped one (which is the default). But why exactly do you want that for an EF context?

Comment: Do you want to change `DbContext` lifetime? You need this `services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Transient);`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto thanks so that I could supply the context from outside because classes participate in a transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will make sure to inject a new instance everytime we call IDBContext object. We need to create a class (repository class) which accepts IDBContext as a constructor parameter such that runtime will inject a new instance every time a call to this class.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyDbContext>(
    options => options.UseSqlServer("<connection string>"),
    ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

Comment: This registers `MyDbContext` as a service.  Where did you get `IDbContext` from?